# ngrx find out which selectors are being triggered

Tags: ngrx

we have a pretty large Angular v13 app which uses ngrx.

Some parts of our application are quite slow. As part of my analysis, I would like to know which - selectors are being fired.

Is there a way to generically add a `console.log` to the selectors? Something like:
`console.log('selector foobar fired!)`. I want to avoid to add `console.log` statements to every single one, though.

This is how we create our selectors:

```
export const selectUser = createSelector(selectAuthState, (state: AuthState) => state.user);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this can't be done with the current API.
However, you can go to your node_modules find the selectors file and add a console log there.

Then, to be sure, you'll also have to clear the angular cache and re-serve the application.

You could also use the DevTools, or the Angular DevTools to find the culprit.

Comment: how would you do so in the devtools? I can only see actions and the state itself, right?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean the redux devtools, but the devtools from the browser. You can profile the application, and then analyze the results.